# Multiple Or conditions with If - PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps-forms, formula

I have 3 individual checkboxes on my Power Apps form and would like to retrieve one value of the 3 checkboxes.

Currently I'm doing the below:

```
If('chkAll_1'.Value = true,'chkAll_1'.Text,"") Or If(chkExternalEvent_1.Value = true,chkExternalEvent_1.Text,"") Or If(chkTeam_1.Value = true,chkTeam_1.Text,"")
```

But its not working and ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do with 3 checkboxes. But try using: `If('chkAll_1'.Value = true, 'chkAll_1'.Text, If(chkExternalEvent_1.Value = true, chkExternalEvent_1.Text, If(chkTeam_1.Value = true, chkTeam_1.Text, "")))`

Comment: Thanks Ganesh actually just worked it out :)

Comment: I have something similar, that I am stuck on. I have to toggles (for Review Complete). If Toggle1=True, set value to Next Approver, If Toggle2=True, set value to Completed). Currently my update value on my Text field is: If(varExec="Yes", "Waiting on HR Approver", If(varHR="Yes", "Completed"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not clear what you are trying to do with 3 checkboxes. But try using:

```
If('chkAll_1'.Value = true, 'chkAll_1'.Text, If(chkExternalEvent_1.Value = true, chkExternalEvent_1.Text, If(chkTeam_1.Value = true, chkTeam_1.Text, "")))
```

**Microsoft documentation**: [If function in Power Apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-if)